# Manually Invoke JSF Validation in Seam Test

Tags: jsf, testing, seam, integration-testing, seam2

I want to write integration tests for my application. I want to test, that the `required=true` attribute on my text components are set on some JSF Pages.

When extending `SeamTest`, I can simulate a `FacesRequest`, and here I can overwrite the `processValidations`Phase. There is a bultin method called `validateValue`, but this is just for Hibernate Validator Validations. So how can I invoke JSF Validators manually? Has anyone done this successfully before?

Is searched the whole JBoss JIRA and the JBoss Forums for a solution, but did not find anything, besides that it was asked very often, but never answered :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Selenium (firefox add-on) for testing.
Once you have recorded the tests, you can export to plain Java code, and use it in your extended SeamTest class, making sure that the values ​​are required = true are in the request.

To learn more, see http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/